# show hidden div with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I have the following:

```
var test = dojo.byId("clientDivision");
test.style.display = 'block';
```

in a function that is getting called as part of an "onChange" of a select.

here is the div I am trying to display:

```
<tr id="divisionInputRow" name="divisionInputRow">
<div id="clientDivisionDiv" >
    <td><label>Org:</label></td>
    <td name="inputDivisionCell" id="inputDivisionCell" class="inputData">

        <div dojoType="customdojo.stores.QueryReadStore" jsId="divisionStore"
        queryTable="" url="/SkillsDB/autocomplete/buildClientDivisionList"
        requestMethod="post"></div>
        <select id="clientDivision" name="clientDivision.name" style ="display:none"
            value="${project?.clientDivision?.encodeAsHTML()}"
            dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" pageSize="15"
            onChange="setCbHiddenId(this, 'clientDivision.id')"
            required="true"
            invalidMessage="Invalid Client Division"
            promptMessage="Enter client division for this project">
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" id="clientDivision.id" name="clientDivision.id" value='${project?.clientDivision?.id}' />          
    </td>
</div>
</tr>
```

so as you can see, there is a select

```
 <select id="clientDivision" name="clientDivision.name" style ="display:none"
```

where i am explicitly setting style to "display:none" so that it's hidden when page loads, I just want to unhide it after an event.

However, the code inmy function doesnt seem to do anything.

Thanks

Comment: isn't the Id "clientDivisionDiv" not "clientDivision"?

Comment: Check the style to ensure the visibility is not set to hidden. That's the only thing I can think of. If you return the element and see what it says, does it show what you expect it to?

Comment: I'd say mess around with it in Firebug or Developer Tools (or whatever your browser has) to look at the styles on that control and make sure changing them indeed has the effect you want.

Comment: What does `alert(test);` display if you add this line before `test.style.display...`?

Comment: @Rodolphe : "[objectHTMLInputElement]"

Comment: @Derek Then I guess we need more code... Since the `select` is found (the `alert` seems to prove it), there has to be something else preventing it from showing up. Maybe a CSS style somewhere? Have you checked with Firebug or JS console as @Mike Christensen has suggested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dojo parses your document, the `<select>` is turned into several tags, looking something like this:

```
<div widgetid="clientDivision" style="display: none;" id="widget_clientDivision" role="combobox">
  <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton ...>
    <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" ...>
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
    <input value="${project?.clientDivision?.encodeAsHTML()}" id="clientDivision"
        name="clientDivision.name" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the DOM node with id "clientDivision" is now hidden deep inside the tag soup. That's why hiding/unhiding it doesn't make sense.

Your combobox is a widget at this point, so treating it like a DOM node (even though it's technically still made up of DOM nodes) doesn't work.

You can hide the widget's outermost DOM node like this:

```
dijit.byId("clientDivision").domNode.style.display = "none";
```

Notice that you have to use `dijit.byId` (not dojo.byId, which is only for DOM nodes, not widgets), and that you have to use its `domNode` member (which is a dijit's outermost DOM node).

Comment: He could also add/remove the dijitHidden CSS class instead of fiddling with the .style directly.